# Exporting environment variables with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I would like to have a consistent way of dealing with environment variables.  For example I have a file `.env.development` containing:

```
# Some comment to be ignored
VAR0='some""" value0'
VAR1="some value1"
VAR2=ignored_value
VAR2=some_value2
```

From a bash shell I can set the shell variables (not the environment variables):

```
$ source .env.development
$ echo $VAR0
some""" value0
$ echo $VAR1
some value1
```

I would also like to make these variables available to subprocesses launched from the shell:

`script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
print("VAR0 is:", os.environ.get("VAR0")
```

As such I need to export these variables.  Using the following is close but retains the quotes needed to allow sourcing the file:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' && export $(grep -v ^# .env.development | xargs -0) && unset IFS && ./script.py
('VAR0 is:', '\'some""" value0\'')
```

I'd like to get the output:

```
('VAR0 is:', 'some""" value0')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore grep, xargs and IFS and use `set -a` with `source`:

```
$ set -a && source .env.development && set +a && ./script.py 
('VAR0 is:', 'some""" value0')
```